# How to send and receive multi-dimensional array from php to Titanium mobile?

Tags: php, ios, multidimensional-array, titanium, type-conversion

I'm new to programming staff and now trying Titanium mobile for IOS app with php and mysql.

problem is, when I got some array data from DB and try to pass to Titanium, "this.responseText" contains "null".

here is the part,

```
    loadReq.onload = function()  
    {  
        var json = this.responseText;
        var response = [];
        response = JSON.parse(json);
        Ti.API.info(response);
    };  

    loadReq.onerror = function(event)
    {
        alert("Network error");
        Ti.API.debug(event);
        Ti.API.info(event);
    };

    loadReq.open("POST","http://localhost/myAppName/post_loading.php");
        var params = {
            userid: win.userid
        };
        loadReq.send(params);
```

and here is my php code.

```
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
    if (!$con)
    {
        echo "Failed to connect.";
        exit;
    }
    $db = mysql_select_db('myAppName');
    if (!$db)
    {
        echo "Failed at selecting db.";
        exit;
    }

    $userid = $_POST['userid'];

    $sql = "here is sql order which will fetch array data based on $userid";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $response = array();

    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $response = $row;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "there is no such data"; 
    }
    ?>
```

array data that php file's getting from DB is like this,

```
    Array(
        [0] => Array(
                'id' => '1',
                'name' => 'name1',
                'sex' => 'm',
                'age' => '20'
               ),
        [1] => Array(
                'id' => '3',
                'name' => 'name3',
                'sex' => 'f',
                'age' => '25'
               ),
        [2] => Array(
                'id' => '5',
                'name' => 'name5',
                'sex' => 'm',
                'age' => '18'
               )
    )
```

I tested some cases to make sure the HTTPClient is working, the sql order is correct in syntax, and single data (not multi-dimensional but just a array, value and words) is able to be passed properly.

However, multi-dimensional array is not available at the moment.
Ti.API.info just telling me the response is "null"

any suggestion?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to set your content-type before you echo the json. Add before the echo:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

This sets a header in the http request so the javascript engine in titanium knows how to properly handle the response data

Comment: Sorry, not sure if this is the solution, but it doesn't hurt to add it and it could fix your problem

Comment: I added but still response null. thank you for your suggestion anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it. just need adding foreach function in php instead of only one echo.

so the answer is;

```
    foreach($responses as $response)
    {
            echo $response;
    }
```

such a simple mistake...took long enough :(
hope this question save many others time.